# What's the best way to quit a job in retail for another job?

Tags: quitting

Yesterday was my first day working retail, and I absolutely hated it. Management is rude, the older employees are snobby, and the customers ignore you and are overall really hard to work with. I know that I could stick it out and it'll probably get better and easier with time, but why do that when I have other employers calling me for interviews? I might like those jobs better and I might get a higher rate of pay. What's the best way to resign from the retail job if I choose to? I read that you're supposed to leave a letter, but I'm not sure if something that formal is necessary for this type of job.

Comment: Voting to close, specific to your employer.  Ask your HR person on what they expect, it may be a letter, verbal, or a call/sms.

Comment: Seems like duplicate of: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/47437/quitting-a-job-after-a-few-days/47514#47514

Answer (score 6):

First day in a throw away non-career job, you are fine doing it over the phone.  "Hey manager, I don't think retail is for me.  Lets end this now and save you wasting money on training me."  Don't bother puting it on your resume or asking for references.