# Very confused about how to go about quitting my retail job?

Tags: quitting

So I was hired by a retail (clothing) store this past Monday. My first day of "training" was Wednesday, and my first day officially on the job was yesterday, Thursday. I have quotes around training because I was actually not trained at all, just thrown on the floor and expected to know what to do. This is my first ever legitimate job. So I'm really irritated because firstly, like I said, I along with the 2 other new hires, were never given training on the job and we were never asked if we have any questions about it. We were also never given a schedule or specific hours, and we weren't given management phone numbers or any phone numbers in general to check if we're working or to just call if we have questions. I want to quit. Scratch that, I WILL quit because I absolutely hate this job and the stress that the disorganization of it is causing me is absolutely ridiculous. Here comes the question - How do you quit a job that does not tell you when you are working and for which you do not even have the phone number for..? I know this sounds absolutely ridiculous, which believe me, is the reason I have been crying in stress for the past 24 hours. In order to get ahold of the manager, if she's even there because she usually isn't, I have to call 5-6 times and talk to the snooty assistant manager who hates me and always acts like I'm a burden. SO. what the heck do i do.

also, if i ever figure out how to get to work and work a shift and get to talk to the manager after, how do i go about quitting

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to quit a job in retail for another job?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/47792/whats-the-best-way-to-quit-a-job-in-retail-for-another-job)

Comment: So how do you know when you _are_ supposed to be working?  I assume you aren't just arbitrarily turning up to work when you think you should be working.  Someone must be telling you your shifts.  Talk to that person.  But be polite!

Comment: @Janes In order to find out if I'm working, I call in around 9am in the morning to ask if I'm working THAT DAY. I am never told in advance. The manager never answers the phone, so I'm forced to talk to the grumpy assistant manager who hates me for no reason, who then forwards me to the manager if she's even there. If she's not, I have to call back a few more times for the next hour or so until I can find out if she wants me to work. Like I said, EXTREMELY disorganized and I waste a big chunk of my morning just figuring out if I have to work later.

Comment: In that case, I think you are fine to just let the assistant manager know.  It's casual work, there is no handover.  Thank them for their time, apologise for feeling that it doesn't fit, hang up and get on with your life :)

Comment: @JaneS Thanks so much. I've been a stressed wreck for the past few days trying to figure out what to do.

Comment: @joestrazzere It really just doesn't feel like the right fit for me, and I have 3 other places that I had applied to along with this one that have been calling me recently for interviews. I feel like I just kind of jumped on this job because it was the first one offered to me and I just really wanted a first job to gain experience, I didn't think very much about whether I would actually enjoy it or even be able to cope with it in general.

Answer (score 4):

Call that grumpy assistant and let her know that you are quitting. Then immediately look for another job.

Don't mention your two-day job or so to your next prospective employer - You are starting from a blank slate, that job was a bad dream.

I'd be surprised if they call you back and tell you that you still have to work for them. If they do, then tell them to specify at which time of which day you are supposed to show up and for how many hours. If they want you to  continue with their rigmarole of you calling five or six times, don't even start the sequence. If they want you, they call you. Otherwise, they are wasting your time.

If someone were to treat me the way they treated you, I wouldn't burn bridges as some other answerer is recommending to you, I'd blow the damn bridges in their faces. I don't need this kind of garbage. Having said that, telling them that you are no longer working for them is sufficient. Your time and energy are better spent looking for a job that has real hours.

Answer (score 0):

I would always say that don't burn bridges. Even if you want to quit, make it as diplomatic/civil as possible. Don't drag yourself down by being so negative about it. Send a resignation letter and hand it over personally to your manager.

In your resignation letter, state the things that made you decide to leave. At least it might help them improve their process. But state it nicely that it won't let them feel really bad. Like I said, be as diplomatic as possible when letting them know about the a negative aspect of the business.

Also, I want to point out that if I were you and I am the breadwinner of the family, I would think twice before quitting. Perhaps I should have saved some amount of money that might support my family for some amount of months before I quit.

Nevertheless, good luck on your plans.

**UPDATE**: Here's a similar question that has answers, you might want to take a look at it. [Quitting a job after a few days?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/47437/quitting-a-job-after-a-few-days?rq=1)

Comment: I will definitely make it as diplomatic/civil as possible, but please take into consideration I have only been working for the company for 2 days.. I don't know if it's necessary to turn in a resignation letter explaining why I'm leaving, I think a simple "this job isn't the right fit for me" might be sufficient. Also, like I said, this is a retail job. I'm 18 years old and a part-time student. I am in no way the "breadwinner of my family."

Comment: "In your resignation letter, state the things that made you decide to leave".  I don't think there's any benefit to doing this.

Comment: there is. when i leave the company i always tell them what makes me leave. if they are open minded, they would be happy that you told them. otherwise, that'll be their problem.
in this case, you might be right because it seems to me that the management might have a hard time accepting such feedback.

Comment: Telling them why you want to leave is never a benefit for you. Go ahead if your reasons say nothing bad about the company (you won the lottery and are never going to work again, or you found a new girlfriend living 1,000 miles away and so on). But anything bad _cannot_ benefit you and _can_ hurt you. For example, if you hadn't ever noticed what a character your boss is, you might find out the hard way after leaving.

Comment: @sara: All you have to do is put in a resignation letter saying that you are leaving. No need to tell them why. They don't care, and it can't benefit you. As disorganised as this place is, I'd ask them to sign that they received your resignation, so when they call you and complain that you didn't turn up for work, you can tell them that you resigned and can prove it. Also helps when disorganised as they are they can't manage to send you any necessary papers (like a P45 if you are in Britain).

Comment: @gnasher729 Is it absolutely necessary to put in a resignation letter? It just feels too formal for a sales associate retail job that I've been working for literally 2 days. I was just planning on calling and talking to the manager or assistant manager.

Comment: @gnasher729, if the reason is positive, i would say you don't need to tell them (well probably just a bit so you won't look rude to them). but if it is something negative then i would say go ahead and tell them where they need to improve. i don't know about you but i am lucky to come from a field where open-mindedness has been a culture. all of my resignation letters contained reasons why i left and they are thankful for the feedback.
besides, telling them gives me a sense of satisfaction because i really want to voice out concerns.